# How to include a string in a razor statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to include a string in a razor statement?

For example, the following code:

```
Page.Title = Resources.HomeStrings_en.Title;
```

I would like to be like so:

```
var locale = "_en";
Page.Title = Resources.HomeStrings + locale + .Title;
```

Clearly, this does not compile, but how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Resources are static classes with a property for each key, so you can't do that.

You need to use ResourceManager.

```
var resset= Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, true, false);
resset.GetString("HomeStrings" + "_en" + ".Title")
```

One thing that makes me think... is that .NET Resources handle the language change using the Culture... going to retrieve the data from the right file. And it seems you are using one file to hold all your languages... and this is not recommended.

Here you can have a tutorial of Internationalization in ASP.NET MVC: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

or this one:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Comment: What do I do to create a resource manager? I'm not quite sure what to look for on google. I have inserted your code into my app and the only parts that are unrecognised are the ResourceManager and Thread. Do I need to import something? @Romias

Comment: I am using separate resource files for each page and each language. @Romias

Comment: You need to import "using System.Resources;"

Comment: And why do you have a suffix like "_en" then?  I use the ResourceManager to generate the keys dynamically, for instance to translate a dropdownlist, using "MyDropDown" + itemId.

Comment: To distinguish between the different locales I am using. @Romias

Comment: I'd like to do it that way but I'm unsure of how to use the ResourceManager or how what the file structure should be. @Romias

Comment: That is why it is weird, the standard way is having files "Resources.en.resx" and "Resources.fr.resx"... but in the code, you always use is as Resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Reflection`. If `HomeStrings` is a property of `Resources` for instance, you can try the following :

```
PropertyInfo property = Resources.GetType().GetProperty("HomeStrings" + locale);
Page.Title = (property.GetValue(Resources) as the type of HomeStrings).Title;
```

Of course it works with attributes, methods, etc. Just make sure to do all the necessary tests: `property != null`, `(... as the type of HomeStrings) != null`,...

Comment: When I try your method I have a compilation error 'The type or namespace name 'PropertyInfo'could not be found'. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you push _ctrl + ._, you will have some help from the _intellisense_, it's a little trick ;) So you must actually simply write `System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`, because this namespace is not included by default in the views.

Comment: Thanks that worked for PropertyInfo but I'm still getting lots of red underlines under Resources, GetType(), 'the type' and 'HomeStrings).Title'. Hmmm  @user3426870

Comment: What are the errors ? Of course it's a resource, so it's a bit different of a classic object.

Comment: Visual Studio says: 'Resources' is a namespace but is used as a variable. Also GetType() does not exist in the namespace 'Resources'. @user3426870